# Is it possible to restart only specific apps in Django, withhout restarting the whole server?

Tags: django, microservices

Similar to the concept of microservices, is there a way to issue a signal to Django (using a script/package), to restart only a specific app?

Let's say we have apps APP1 and APP2, each being developed by a different developer, with shared interdependancies, all in the same Django project. The project is live in production, and rather than restart the whole server, inducing unnecessary downtime for unrelated features, we just want to reload the code existing in APP1.

Currently using apache + gunicorn

Comment: No. An app is just a logical group of models and views, it's not a separate service.

Comment: Is there another approach to breakdown into separate services? Without the need to create separate projects?

Comment: You'd need to create different `settings` for different services. All sharing common options but having different `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then you should run an individual process for each service with its `settings` module.

Comment: Is this a good approach to tackle the problem? Or is it better to have separate projects, knowing that there is much in common between the apps? And are there any tutorials doing something similar?